# Build Error Eclipse with Android OpenCV and NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am new to Android+OpenCV+NDK, while configuring Eclipse Juno.
I have followed the steps given in 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#android-dev-intro
Manual Environment setup for Android.

I am trying to work the sample programs given in OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk.zip that I downloaded from the link given in Introduction in Android Development(Above link). But for few days I am stuck at the build error,

**** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing ****

> D:\Softwares-x64\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd 
>   Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in       linker flags: -lopencv_java
>   Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
>   Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
>   Android NDK:     current module
>   [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

I have tried modifying APP_ABI from armeabi-v7a to all in application.mk file.  But still I get errors as

> D:\Softwares-x64\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd 
>   Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java
>   Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
>   Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
>   Android NDK:     current module
>
> [arm64-v8a] Compile++      : mixed_sample <= jni_part.cpp
>   [arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libmixed_sample.so
>   D:/Softwares-x64/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_java
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make.exe: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libmixed_sample.so] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****

The android.mk is

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include D:/Softwares-x64/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please help me out...!!!
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I have the same error for Arm64 in Android Studio.